# AntiforgeryValidationException: The provided anti forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user than the current user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm not sure what's going on here, but I'm seeing 2 different tokens in my cookie. One is "XSRF-TOKEN", and the other is ".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.OnvOIX6Mzn8", and they have different values.

I'm using ASP.Net Core 2.1, with SPA set (and Angular on the front end) and I have the following in Startup.cs.

I don't know what's creating that latter token, as it doesn't seem to be from any of the code I added.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(
            builder =>
            {
            builder.Run(
                async context =>
                {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

                var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                if (error != null)
                {
                    context.Response.AddApplicationError(error.Error.Message);
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(error.Error.Message).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                });
            });
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseJwtTokenMiddleware();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
            spa.UseSpaPrerendering(options =>
            {
                options.BootModulePath = $"{spa.Options.SourcePath}/dist/server/main.js";
                options.BootModuleBuilder = env.IsDevelopment()
                    ? new AngularCliBuilder(npmScript: "build:ssr")
                    : null;
                options.ExcludeUrls = new[] { "/sockjs-node" };
            });

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });

        app.UseMiddleware<AntiForgeryMiddleware>("XSRF-TOKEN");
    }
}

public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseAntiforgeryTokenMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder, string requestTokenCookieName)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<AntiForgeryMiddleware>(requestTokenCookieName);
    }
}

public class AntiForgeryMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;
    private readonly string requestTokenCookieName;
    private readonly string[] httpVerbs = new string[] { "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "TRACE" };

public AntiForgeryMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, string requestTokenCookieName)
{
    this.next = next;
    this.requestTokenCookieName = requestTokenCookieName;
}

public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
{
    if (httpVerbs.Contains(context.Request.Method, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);

        context.Response.Cookies.Append(requestTokenCookieName, tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions()
        {
            HttpOnly = false
        });
    }

    await next.Invoke(context);
}
```

}

Comment: I am not using the form tag-helper. I haven't mentioned it in my originally post, but I have updated it to say that it has an Angular SPA, and it is prerendered. I don't use Razor.

Answer (score 4):

The `.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.OnvOIX6Mzn8` cookie in your example is being generated by the call to `GetAndStoreTokens`. This call generates *two* tokens:

1. The "Cookie Token": This is what gets written as `.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.OnvOIX6Mzn8`.
2. The "Request Token": This is a separate token that gets paired with the "Cookie Token". You write this value out as a cookie yourself (namely `XSRF-TOKEN`) as is shown in your code.

You can see this in your example, if you examine the value of the generated value `tokens`. This has two properties of interest: `RequestToken` and `CookieToken`. The `GetAndStoreTokens` call is writing out the `CookieToken` value and your code is writing out the `RequestToken` value, which explains why you are seeing two different values in the two different cookies.

The code you have for this appears to come directly from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configure-antiforgery-features-with-iantiforgery), which explains that:

> ...uses middleware from the app's home page to generate an antiforgery token and send it in the response as a cookie (using the default Angular naming convention described later in this topic)...

When sending a request to the server that needs to be validated according to the antiforgery rules, both the cookie and a corresponding header are required. The ASP.NET Core Antiforgery system matches the "Request Token" and the "Cookie Token" together during the validation process.

Further down in the docs, you'll see:

> ...using local storage to store the antiforgery token on the client and sending the token as a request header is a recommended approach.

The JavaScript example that follows shows how the `RequestToken` value is added to the XHR request using a custom request header (namely `RequestVerificationToken`). The docs also show that this header can be changed when registering the Antiforgery services in the ASP.NET Core DI system:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN");
```

You need to read the value of the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie in your Angular application and send it back to the server with your API requests. You can use the default header name (as I mentioned above) or customise it (also mentioned above). AS @Sal has pointed out in his answer, AngularJs has a built-in mechanism for this so long as the cookie name is `XSRF-TOKEN` ([this is also the same for Angular](https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection)).

Hopefully, that explains the two tokens and the general Antiforgery process. However, from the fact that you're writing out a correctly named cookie for Angular's default `HttpClient` XSRF protection, I expect that all of this side of things is configured correctly.

In terms of where your problem might lie, I'm suspicious of the location of this line:

```
app.UseMiddleware<AntiForgeryMiddleware>("XSRF-TOKEN");
```

Given that this is the last call in your pipeline setup code, it will only run *after* the MVC pipeline and only in cases where the MVC pipeline does not handle the request. To address this, move the call *above* `UseMvc` - This might be a bit aggressive in that it will generate new "Request Token"s more than will be necessary, but it will confirm whether or not that's your issue.

Comment: I tried putting it elsewhere (including above UseMvc) but I'm still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

By default AspNetCore creates a cookie with the "AspNetCore.AntiForgery.XXX" (unless renamed by your configuration) to prevent xsrf/csrf attacks.

I've also read in this [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.1) that AngularJS also has an automatic way of handling xsrf/csrf scenarios:

> AngularJS uses a convention to address CSRF. If the server sends a cookie with the name XSRF-TOKEN, the AngularJS $http service adds the
>   cookie value to a header when it sends a request to the server. This
>   process is automatic. The header doesn't need to be set explicitly.
>   The header name is X-XSRF-TOKEN. The server should detect this header
>   and validate its contents.
>       For ASP.NET Core API work with this convention:
>       Configure your app to provide a token in a cookie called XSRF-TOKEN.
>       Configure the antiforgery service to look for a header named X-XSRF-TOKEN.
>
> services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");

Could it be that your application is configured to generate both the default AntiForgery cookie and the XSRF-TOKEN?
If that were the case you might be generating and receiving two different anti forgery tokens which might be causing the problem

Comment: I don't see where the other AspNetCore.Antiforgery.XXX is being generated. If I take out my custom code ("app.UseMiddleware<AntiForgeryMiddleware>("XSRF-TOKEN");"), it doesn't generate either token.

Comment: Can you try removing your custom code and try customizing the token from `Startup.ConfigureService` something like: `services.AddAntiforgery(options => 
{
    options.CookieName = "XSRF-TOKEN";
    options.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN";
});`

Comment: I don't get any token back. The code AddAntiforgery does not send the token explicitly. (Note that I'm using SpaPrerendering.)